# Override the file customizer.php in zerif lite

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, overriding

I want to override, the file `customizer.php`, in zerif lite child. 
I have already tried to copy the `customizer.php` in child but the file are ignored.

Comment: please provide code example of what you got

Comment: that link is good for reference, but the important parts of your code should be copied here for future reference. In case the site is down, or your code in repo will change over time. Also update your question with the link and code. Don't just add it to the comments. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. ...